# How to fix simple error in moving ".slice()" into setup() as a computed function?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, v-for

I'm using Vuejs3 and trying to move `.slice(0,3)` (limits v-for to 3) into a computed function in the setup(), in order to limit the number of elements in a v-for (that happens to be nested in another v-for).

Everything works as intended before the change, using the following code:

```
<ul class="mt-4">
  <div v-for="review in prime.allReviews" :key="review">
    <li v-for="pro in review.propPros.slice(0, 3)" :key="pro">
      {{ pro }}
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

When I try to move the `slice(0, 3)` into the setup() as a computed function, per a dozen suggestions it's best practice to do so, the DOM goes blank. Here's the code causing the problem:

```
<ul class="mt-4">
  <div v-for="review in prime.allReviews" :key="review">
    <li v-for="pro in limitedPros" :key="pro">
    {{ pro }}
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

And in setup():

```
const limitedPros = computed(() => {
      return review.propPros.slice(0, 3);
  });

... 

return {
  limitedPros,
};
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass `review` to function, without computed property:
(When you want to loop `review` you need to know which one)

```js
const { ref } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const prime = ref({allReviews: [{propPros: [1,2,3,4,5]}, {propPros: [6,7,8,9]}]})
    const limitedPros = (review) => {
      return review.propPros.slice(0, 3);
    };
    return { limitedPros, prime };
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <ul class="mt-4">
    <div v-for="review in prime.allReviews" :key="review">
      <li v-for="pro in limitedPros(review)" :key="pro">
      {{ pro }}
      </li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Nikola I'll investigate your idea, but I'm really trying to understand the mistake I'm making and learn the right way to implement it.

Comment: @Mark Gavagan hey mate, You are welcome :) Where do you get `review` that you refer to in computed property? There is a mistake I think.

Comment: Gracias @Nikola. This is all in Vuejs3 and 'review' refers to each item in the allReviews array being cycled-through using v-for ('allReviews' are fetcheded from from Firebase - everything works perfectly until I move it into setup() as a computed property).

Comment: Yes I got it, but you want to access review that you get in outer loop, so you need to pass it to function and return data to loop thru. In other words you don't know in computed property which review to loop thru.

Comment: Ah, that makes makes sense. I am grateful and will try it out ASAP. Best, -M